# Moving JsonResult Actions from Controller to a separate Helper class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a couple of Actions in my AccountController class initially that I would like to move to a separate class of their own. I created a new class file in a /Helpers folder.

This class needs to be URL accessible from client side jQuery Ajax. The class methods also return a JsonResult as coded now. For both of these reasons, is it correct that this Helper class needs to have a base class of Controller and that it should probably be placed in the /Controllers folder for consistency?

If this helper class needs to be based on the Controller class to be accessible by URL, then it also requires a View page?

Comment: Well, if it needs to be accessible for incoming requests then it *has* to be a Controller, and as such should reside in the 'Controllers' directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it correct that this Helper class needs to have a base class of Controller

Yes, in order for actions to be accessible through routing engine, you need to derive from `Controller` or any other class that has `Controller` as base class.

> it should probably be placed in the /Controllers folder for consistency?

Yes that make sense.

> If this helper class needs to be based on the Controller class to be accessible by URL, then it also requires a View page?

Not really, as you mentioned that the methods are returning `JsonResult`, in that case no need to have a corresponding view. Only if you want to return an HTML output, you need a view to be returned as `ActionResult`.